# JPA entity.save(EntityManager) anti-pattern

Tags: jpa, anti-patterns

I was thinking to implement an anti-pattern, since `@EntityListener`s are in some case insufficient:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable
{
    ...

    public abstract AbstractEntity save(EntityManager em);

    ...
}

@Entity
public class ConcreteEntity extends AbstractEntity
{
    ...

    public ConcreteEntity save(EntityManager em)
    {
        doSomeStuff(this);

        ConcreteEntity merged;
        if(id == null)
        {
            em.persist(this);
            merged = this;
        }
        else
        {
            merged = em.merge(this);
        }

        doOtherStuff(merged);

        return merged;
    }

    ...
}
```

PRO:

- specific business logic is inside Object (**REAL** OO programming)
- make use of inheritance to control business logic (another OO pattern)
- can write generic EJB

CON:

- not called on cascade
- contract addition: forbidden to call `em.persist(entity)`/`em.merge(entity)`

Is there something else I'm forgetting?

Comment: Isn't it just `ActiveRecord` pattern expanded to include Listeners (`@PreInsert` etc..) stuff?

Comment: Didn't know about this. Yes, it is :)

Answer (score 2):

CON:

- With DAO logic in entities you're opening a pandora box. If persistence logic is allowed in entities, then why not presentation logic as well? And so on. Then, why not `find...`-methods as well?
- Bypasses layer isolation. If persistence logic is concentrated in DAOs, it is easier to control, what's being done.
- Will break the business component isolation. (I don't even expose DAOs between business components in my projects, only business service - one layer higher.)
- Moves the focus in the entity from modelling the business object to "we just handle some data here". I doubte the purpose of the business object like, say `Contract` is to persist itself using certain technology.

Comment: What's the difference between DAO and Business Service?

Comment: This is a different question. :) Please ask it separately.